# rails4 rake assets precompile in production environment generate wrong javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm working on deploy my rails application and I found that error always exists in my javascript file when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile`.But when I run `rails assets:precompile` to generate js file, it works well.Is there any differences between production and development in precompile phase? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile, i hope you don't have different gemset in production

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: what error it's displaying ?

Comment: The precompile can run without error, but the js file it generates has error. This causes my website can access but can't work.

Comment: have you checked the folder access permission and javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have **permission** to generate compiled javascript file, to **trace** your error, run the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile --trace
```

**Solution of permission issue:**

Try to run the command as **sudo** as the following:

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile --trace
```